# disabling tab navigation through action bar if tab validation fails

Tags: android, tabs

I am running an app with 3 tabs that support both swiping and action bar for tab navigation. i set up a validation check so that it when tab 2 is selected, if certain requirements arent met, it returns to tab 1.
It works well with swiping (if swiping from tab1 to tab2, it displays the error message and returns to tab 1) but with the action bar, if an action bar button is pressed for tab2, the error message is displayed and tab1's view displayed but the action bar button remains on the tab 2.

I had tried the following script but with no luck of changing the active tab button back to the first tab. This is especially a problem since data is supposed to be saved to sqlite when whenever a new tab is selected.

```
 public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    check = GlobalApp.data().value;

    if(tab.getTag() == "Product")
    {
        if(check == "Select Client")
        {

            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(0);
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            alert.showAlertDialog(Invoice2.this,
                    "Error",
                    "Client name not selected", true);


        }
        else
        {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }
    }
    else if ((tab.getTag() == "Confirm"))
    {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First bind the tabs to the `ViewPager`:

```
ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            //Do the criteria check here; AFTER setting current item.
        }
```

then `Viewpager` to the tabs:

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(
        new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                //Do the criteria check here; AFTER setting current item.
            }
        });
```

After that you can perform check for your criteria after commented lines. Regardless of you changing the tab or page, your tabs and your pages should change synchronously. For more info check this [Android Developers training page](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#swipe-tabs)